# Asp.net MVC Routelink null controller parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have two routes, the default one

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I added another route, sometimes the parameter will by a string

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ByName",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{name}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", name = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

When I use the "ByName" route in a RouteLink, the URL is fine, but the parameter in my controller is empty

In the view:

```
@Html.RouteLink(application.Nom, "ByName", new {controller= "Packaging", action = "EditApplication", name = application.Nom})
```

The controller

```
public ActionResult EditApplication(string name)
```

URL result is fine: .../Packaging/EditApplication/VisualStudio, but the parameter value stays null. Why?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have `TWO` Routes with same parameters and same definition, first one will take precedence. Instead, you need to have something like shown below with specific constraints in routes.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ByName",
        url: "sample/{action}/{name}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", name = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

 routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: Indeed this works, you would think that named routes would get over this, but it does not.

Thank you!